# Adding a sun glow effect to a sphere

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have rendered a 3D sphere representing the Sun. It looks quite boring, so I'd like to add an effect similar to this around the sphere:

http://glsl.heroku.com/e#15604.0

I just really have no idea where to begin, as that shader is 2D and I need to apply it for 3D

Comment: replace your sphere with a simple quad and render it with this shadder